# The “Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform” WARN

Tags: hadoop, installation

It's my first question in stack overflow, so please apologize for any mistakes made !!

Im with the hadoop ecosystem ...

Did first two installations ... and:

1) First install 
on ubuntu 16.04 LTS ..  hadoop 2.8.4 (downloaded from apache site )
installed in pseudo-cluster mode, 1 node ...
till now ... every think works fine.

in /opt/hadoop/lib/native 
there is this:

```
total 5024
    4096 May  7 23:58 .
    4096 May  7 23:58 ..
    4096 May  7 23:58 examples
 1439746 May  7 23:58 libhadoop.a
 1632592 May  7 23:58 libhadooppipes.a
      18 May  7 23:58 libhadoop.so -> libhadoop.so.1.0.0
  841925 May  7 23:58 libhadoop.so.1.0.0
  476106 May  7 23:58 libhadooputils.a
  446548 May  7 23:58 libhdfs.a
      16 May  7 23:58 libhdfs.so -> libhdfs.so.0.0.0
  281612 May  7 23:58 libhdfs.so.0.0.
```

2) Second install
on ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 3 node server cluster  hadoop 2.6.0 chd 5.15.1 
(downloaded from cloudera tarball CDH5 )

I´ve got the  “Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform” WARN 
and found that /opt/hadoop/lib/native es empty !!!

I find only indications to download source and re compile ...

Why the libraries are in version 2.8 of the apache site and are not in this CDH distribution ?? 
How do I get them? 
Can you guide me? 
Thank you very much  !

Ernesto

Comment: Cloudera doesn't have to include the native libraries... Not sure why you'd want to use an older version of Hadoop anyway, but as you've found, you need to compile them, so whatever source you find that said that should tell you how as well

Comment: For the first tests, I downloaded version 2.8. But as I plan to add other products of the set (hive etc), I thought it was better to install a set of products already tested together, so I continued with the cdh 5.15 ... Also, as in 2.8 the libraries were in the set, I assumed that they should also be in the other distributions. Well, ok, I will investigate how to compile them! ... thanks for the reply !

Comment: I've been using Hortonworks most recently, not Cloudera, but it makes sense to me that they just offer the software tested together, not guarantee that CPU specific C libraries are available

Comment: agree !. tks for the comment !